# Access denied for user PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following error when trying to connect to database using PHP:

> Access denied for user 'alexizh@localhost' (using password: NO)

I know this has been asked a few times but all of the other questions that I found like mine don't really help at all. The main reason is because my username is actually 'alexiz'. I have 4 other databases and never had this issue with any of them. Here are my config.php and connection.php files:

config.php

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'alexiz');
define('DB_PASS', 'password');
define('DB_NAME', 'database1');

?>
```

connection.php

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';

class DB_Connection {

private $connect;

function __construct() {
    $this->connect = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die("DB connection error");
}

public function get_connection() {
    return $this->connect;
}

?>
```

Comment: Do note that it says you are sending no password, I would start with that.

Comment: If password NO than use `define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');`

Comment: @Valdorous I noticed that, but I am entering a PW and the username it is telling me is different than the one that I am actually using.

Comment: @devpro I just tried that and now when I try to run it, it won't do anything at all.

Comment: Facing same error ??

Comment: @devpro no error now but it still doesn't do anything. I have a register.php file that is supposed to register a user and it isn't doing anything.

Comment: Did u checked what r u getting in `$this->connect;`

Comment: I attempted to utilise a similar setup quickly and found no issue. I recommend var_dumping the DB_PASS in the construct.

Comment: I get a feeling those names are already in use or are being set by another "config" of yours. Try renaming them or debugging in either the config or DB_connection class. should get you the answer.